# Running unit test : Karma + Jasmine gives undefined function `controller` error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to implement the unit testing in existing angular project. For that I've added Grunt-Karma

```
karma:
      unit:
          options:
              frameworks: ['jasmine'],
              singleRun: true,
              browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
              files: [bower js files + project dev/test js files]
```

Controller is,

```
angular.module('app.lol.ctrls', []).controller('LOLCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$filter', 'Resource', '$log', function($scope, $filter, Resource, $log) {//some logic}
```

And test spec is

```
describe('Controller: LOLCtrl', function () {
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var OrderCtrl;
    var scope;
    var filter;
    var log;
    var resource=someResourceWithSomeDataFunc;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, $filter, $log) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        OrderCtrl = $controller('LOLCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $filter: filter,
            Resource: resource,
            $log: log
        });
    }));

    it('should have lolVar to be undefined', function () {
        expect(scope.lolVar).toBeUndefined();
    });
});
```

When I run the test, I'm getting error

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) Controller: LOLCtrl should have lolVar to be undefined FAILED
    Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'LOLCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/ng/areq?p0=LOLCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    undefined
        at assertArg ....
```

I tried the solutions like using `angular.mock.module` instead of `module` in `beforeEach`. Also I've double checked whether I'm including the controller file.
Also the `app.lol.ctrls` is injected in `app` itself. I tried `beforeEach(module(app.lol.ctrls))`, but that too gives same error.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first I think you forgot to include the dependencies of your module. without knowing the complete structure of your app-code, I guess that the code, where you defined your controller should be

```
angular.module('app.lol.ctrls', ['app.lol', '/*maybe other dependecies*/']).controller('LOLCtrl', [ ]);
```

or did you have a own module file? then it should look like this:

```
angular.module('app.lol.ctrls').controller('LOLCtrl', [ ]);
```

after resolving these dependency-problems, have a look on your index.html. Did you included
`<script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>`?
if not, install angular-mocks and include it.

then, as a second step, go to your test spec and add change the beforeEach parts like this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    module('app.lol.ctrls');
    module('ngMockE2E');
});
```

try to run your tests again. if you're getting the same error like before, have a look at your grunt-file. the list of your files included by karma looks a little bit strange for me. maybe this could be a problem too. for help, here a snipped from my grunt-file:

```
karma: {  
        options: {
            frameworks: ['jasmine'],
            files: [
                '<%= dom_munger.data.appjs %>',
                    //this files data is also updated in the watch handler, if updated change there too
                    'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
                    'application/**/*-spec.js',
                    'application/**/*.html',
                    'base/**/*-spec.js',
                    'error/**/*.html',
                    'html/**/*.html',
                    '*.html',
                    'bower_components/**/*.html'
            ],
            preprocessors: {
                '**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
            },
            ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
                moduleName: 'templates'
            },
            logLevel: 'WARN',
            reporters: ['mocha'],
            captureConsole: true,
            autoWatch: false,
            singleRun: true
        }
  }
```

I hope, this will help you a little bit to resolve your problem.